# Using EXPECT Script to log into a switch and print what is displayed on the terminal to a CSV file

Tags: bash, unix, tcl, expect

Using **EXPECT** Script, I am logging into an Ethernet Switch and running a command that displays information on cable status (as shown below). How can I print the output displayed on the terminal and place into a comma separated value file?

The "Pair" and "Length" values can change.

[image]

The "PA" represents "Pair A" and "LA" represents the "Length" this happens for each pair and respective length.

[image: !My desired output is to be printed to a CSV file.[2]]

This code works it displays the CABLEstats to the terminal. I need it saved to a file and formatted to CSV.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set $PROMPT "# "
set $PASSWORD "assword\r"
set $CABLEstats "show interface Ethernet 1/1-20 cable-stats\r"

spawn ssh admin@192.111.111.1
expect -re "password: " {send "$PASSWORD"}
expect $PROMPT
send $CABLEstats
expect $PROMPT

interact
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do some string manipulation with `$expect_out(buffer)` which contains the command output, but also contains the command you sent and the prompt you matched.

Something like:

```
send $CABLEstats
expect $PROMPT

set fh [open output_data.csv w]
foreach line [split $expect_out(buffer) \n] {
    if {[string match {*Ethernet*} $line]} {
        set line [regsub {^[^/]+/} $line ""]  ;# remove up to the first slash
        puts $fh [regsub -all {\s+} $line ,]
    }
}
close $fh

expect eof
```

Comment: Can you comment on each line of code you answered with? I am receiving an error     'wrong # args should be "foreach varList list ?varList list....? command" '

Comment: @aCUDDLYduck Sounds like a cut-n-paste error on your part; glenn's code is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is deceptively tricky, since the table of stats could be longer than expect's buffer (individual lines rarely are, but tables can easily get long). Because of that, you want to have some expect processing to extract things by line and process them piecemeal.

```
# ...
send $CABLEstats
set fh [open output_data.csv w]
expect {
    $PROMPT {
        # We've seen a prompt again; stop processing and print the timestamp
        puts $fh ""
        # Not sure what format of timestamp to use :-)
        puts $fh [clock format [clock seconds]]
    }
    -re {Ethernet[^/]*/(.*)$} {
        # This line has data to report
        puts $fh [regsub -all {\s+} $expect_out(1,string) ","]
        exp_continue;        # KEEP WAITING FOR INPUT!
    }
}
close $fh

interact
```

What's going on here? I'm using the multiple-bodies form of `expect` which lets it search for two (or more) things at once and run a little script when they arrive. The order matters; the search patterns are checked in order each time some new input arrives. When a pattern matches, it's body script is run and the `expect` terminates afterwards *unless the script finishes with `exp_continue`.* Patterns are matched exactly unless told otherwise; the `-re` flag says “match the next one as a regular expression” and `Ethernet[^/]*/(.*)$` is a regular expression that matches every line with `Ethernet` in it and a `/` somewhere afterwards while *capturing* the string after that `/`. The captured string is placed in the variable `expect_out(1,string)` as it is the string version of the first (and only) captured substring. (You can get it in index form too, but that's rarely wanted.)

This is great as it means we can process the data by lines, write the termination condition as the prompt, and combine the match and extract into one fairly succinct command.